# Photoshop CS6 - Creating figure

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am not so familiar with Photoshop and would like to ask for help with something that is probably quite easy for many people, I have tried searching around without any exact help to what I want.

What I want to create is the following (without the text and no yellow background color)

[image]

If anyone know how to do it or to tell me any link to a web tutorial that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create a rounded rectangle (U). Use this for reference:
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/shapes/photoshop-shape-essentials/

Then, you will transform the rounded rectangle (ctrl + t). Use this for reference:
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/free-transform/

Next, you can apply a gradient to the rounded rectangle (right click the shape layer in the layers panel and click blending options). Use this for reference:
http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/tools/gradient-overlay-layer-styles/

Last, create a new layer (ctrl + shift + N) and you can use the text tool to create the text you desire. Reference: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/type/photoshop-type-essentials/

Answer (score 0):

Just the red shape?

Right click "rectangle tool" and choose "Rounded rectangle tool".
You can then adjust the "roundness" by selecting a radius value.

(Short tutorial: http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/shapes/rounded-corners.html)

If you want the "tilt" you can use Edit -> Transform -> Perspective

Comment: I got the rounded corner rectable but i cant see any transform menu in the edit menu

Comment: Found what i was looking for, it was called "Free Transform Path" in Edit menu, thank you for the help!

Comment: Or wait, if you look at the provided link image its not really the same using the transform as it only rotates the image?

Comment: Perspective gives the desired effect.. I thought it was under "Edit -> transform -> perspective".. I'm trying to find out where it is ^^

Comment: http://webdoubts.com/software/photoshop-perspective-transform.gif You dont have that?